# Magento2 catalog search results append some additional product ids

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch, elasticsearch, programatically

I have a requirement to apply some custom logic in catalog search results and retrieve some additional products in search results if i search for certain text in a global search. I have used **catalog_block_product_list_collection** event observer and tried to append additional products in search results, it worked but sorting, filtering and pagination are not working properly with it. I know Magento uses elastic search for search. Can anyone help with this requirement? is there any easy way to append some products to search results?

```
protected $productFactory;

/**
 * @param ProductFactory $productFactory
 */
public function __construct(
    ProductFactory $productFactory
) {
    $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
}

/**
 * Add custom products to the product collection.
 *
 * @param Observer $observer
 */
public function execute(Observer $observer)
{
    $productCollection = $observer->getData('collection');
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $productRepository = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface');
    $request  = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface');
    $paramValue = $request->getParam('q');
    if ($paramValue !== null) {
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $productCollection */
        //$productCollection = $observer->getData('collection');
        //echo '<pre>';print_r($searchCollection->getData());die;

        // Add your custom logic to load additional products
        $customProductSkus = ['1','2','3']; // Replace with your product IDs
        if (count($customProductSkus) > 0) {
            foreach ($customProductSkus as $sku) {
                try {
                    $product = $productRepository->get($sku);
                    if (!$productCollection->getItemById($product->getId())) {
                        $productCollection->addItem($product);
                    }
                }
                catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e) {
                    
                }
            }
        }
        $pageSize = $productCollection->getPageSize();
        $currentPage = $productCollection->getCurPage();

        // Apply custom logic here

        $productCollection->setPageSize($pageSize);
        $productCollection->setCurPage($currentPage);
        /*$direction = $productCollection->getOrderDirection();
        $field = $productCollection->getOrderField();
        $productCollection->setOrder($field, $direction);*/

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share your code here?

Comment: Are you using Magento default elastic search extension or added any third party elastic search extension like and Amasty, I am asking because the ans of this question is very depend on the elastic search extension.

Comment: yes I am using default elastic search but one third-party plugin has overridden the default catalog search results to accommodate Ajax layered navigation

Comment: @Msquare i have added code sample in my question. please check